# What are the implications of dividing a Rails app into multiple gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, rubygems

I am working on programming a CMS in Ruby on Rails and am wondering about the implications of dividing the app into engines (stored as gems). What would the implications be?

Comment: If those components are reusable or you want to develop microservices, then definitely you can divide the app in smaller engines and gems.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai You should add this statement as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails Engines is a not very popular Rails feature.
It's not that it's bad, far from that, but it just didn't catch that well. The cases in which using one makes sense are not that many, and there are a lot of Rails developers which doesn't even know of the existence of Engines.

A Rails Engine is most useful when you have some functionality that is so standard and common that you want to use it across multiple Rails projects.

You should listen to [Sean Devine's podcast episode](http://5by5.tv/rubyonrails/198) on this matter. It goes quite in detail discussing the implications, and why you might want to build a Rails Engine.

Answer (score 0):

If those components are reusable or you want to develop microservices, then definitely you can divide the app in smaller engines and gems.